# computed field that does not compute and default that does not work (odoo-12)

Tags: odoo-12

I have this field with a method in my model which aims to detect the changes in the many2one:

```
manytoone = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="product.template", string="Many to One",
                                required=False, )

cambio_realizado = fields.Boolean(string="Cambios en Many to One", default=False)

@api.onchange('manytoone')
def _detectar_cambio(self):
    self.cambio_realizado = True
```

No works the default=False in Boolean Field. Always start in True.

And the other problem is that no works a computed field:

```
@api.multi
def computer_function(self):
    self.computation = 243+234

    computation = fields.Float(string="Result: ", compute=computer_function, readonly=True)
```

The result is zero... always in the view.

identation ok, and the model is inherited

My Class and my view with the tips:

```
class CustomModule(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    name = fields.Char('campos relacionales, decoradores onchange y funcion computar')

    manytoone = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="product.template", string="Many to One",
                                required=False, )

    cambio_realizado = fields.Boolean(string="Cambios en Many to One")

    @api.onchange('manytoone')
    def _detectar_cambio(self):
        self.cambio_realizado = True

    onetomany = fields.One2many(comodel_name="sale.order", inverse_name="manytoone",
                                    string="One to Many", required=False, )
    manytomany = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="sale.order",
                                     relation="sale_handler",
                                  column1="order_id", column2="order_handler_id",
                                  string="Many to Many", )

    @api.depends('computation')
    def computer_function(self):
        for record in self:
            record.computation = 300

    computation = fields.Float(string="Result: ", compute=computer_function, readonly=True)

<odoo>
<!-- Inherit Form View to Modify it -->
<record id="custom_view_custom" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">custom.view.custom</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <xpath expr="//sheet" position="inside">
            <group>
            <field name="manytoone"/>
            <field name="onetomany"/>
            <field name="manytomany"/>
            </group>
            <group>
                <field name="computation"/>
                <field name="cambio_realizado"/>
            </group>
        </xpath>

    </field>
</record>

</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0):

@api.one
def computer_function(self):
    self.computation = 243+234

```
computation = fields.Float(string="Result: ", compute=computer_function, readonly=True)
```

use @api.one in your code

Comment: What is the different one or multi? 
No works with @api.one too.

Answer (score 0):

1- onchnage, when you try to create a new record, the onchange called automatically then cambio_realizado set to true

```
@api.onchange('manytoone')
def _detectar_cambio(self):
    for o in self:
        if o.manytoone:
            o.cambio_realizado = True
```

2- in compute it's preferally to use api.depends('somefield'), but the code bellow may be work for you, use a loop and don't use readonly

```
@api.multi
def computer_function(self):
    for o in self:
        o.computation = 243+234

computation2 = fields.Float(string="Result: ", compute=computer_function)
```

Comment: 1. Oh, and how can we avoid being called in the beginning? That, I want start False, and only change when change the field. 

2. How frustrating, nothing works. I will copy all the code again in case I have left some details, since I have tried several combinations. (I will edit the question with all the code)

Comment: But false is a value changed :) , if you use 'if o.manytoone' then o.cambio_realizado = True executed just when o.manytoone is not Empty